Как найти строку во всех таблицах базы?
Я вывел список баз таким образом:
        with open("output.log", "a") as outfile:
                outfile.write("... Подключаюсь к БД."+"\n")
        try: 
            mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                host="IP",
                user="USER",
                password="DB",
            )
            with open("output.log", "a") as outfile:
                    outfile.write("+ Успешное подключение к БД."+"\n")
        except mysqldb.Error as e: 
            print(f"Error connecting to MYSQL Platform: {e}") 
            with open("output.log", "a") as outfile:
                outfile.write(f"- Error connecting to MYSQL Platform: {e}\n")
            sys.exit(1)
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        listdbs = []
        querrydb = ("SHOW DATABASES")
        mycursor.execute(querrydb)
        for querrydb in mycursor:
            #print(querrydb[0])
            listdbs.append(querrydb[0])
        with open("output.log", "a") as outfile:
            outfile.write("+ Отображаю список БД."+"\n")
        print("Что хотите найти: ")
        choiceword = input()
        with open("output.log", "a") as outfile:
            outfile.write("+ Поиск слов: "+choiceword+"\n")
        for db in listdbs:
            print(db)

как мне в выбранной базе найти строку или число во всех таблицах через python? пусть они будут повторяться

Перебрать по одной все базы, в каждой - все таблицы, и из каждой таблицы запросом получить требуемую запись. Кстати, базы можно не получать, лучше сразу получать список таблиц из INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, а если поле имеет определённое имя - то сразу из INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.

Но вообще базы и таблицы обычно настолько разнородные, что искать там что-то, не глядя на их структуру, не пользуясь знанием, какая где лежит сущность - странновато.

Такое можно сделать, вопрос зачем такое делать? Скорее всего, если вы дадите ответ на вопрос зачем так делать, вам подскажут как это сделать без перебора всей базы целиком)

@Dezmonder, Я хочу скриптом вывести таблицы в базе, в которой есть опредедленная ячейка
